# Justifying the transverse-traceless gauge

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, gauge, linearized-theory

For weak gravitational fields, we can assume the metric is some perturbation of flat space: $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + h_{ab}$. Following Schutz's argument, you can incorporate a small coordinate transformation $x^a \leftarrow x^a + \xi^a$, then you could show that the trace reverse of $h_{ab}$ denoted as $\bar{h}^{ab} = h^{ab} - (1/2)\eta^{ab}h$ transforms like:
$$\bar{h}_{ab} \leftarrow \bar{h}_{ab} - \partial_b\xi_a - \partial_a\xi_b + \eta_{ab}\partial_i\xi^i$$
The gauge condition $\partial_b\bar{h}^{ab} = 0$ can always be chosen since:
$$\square\xi^a = \partial_b\bar{h}^{\text{(old)}\ ab}$$
and this has a well defined solution.
This makes sense until in Schutz's chapter 9 on the transverse-traceless gauge where he asserts that we can add additional constraints by leveraging Gauge freedom. He claims that we can impose the additional restriction:
$$\square\xi_a = 0$$
I don't understand the justification for this. This seems to imply that you can freely assume $\partial_b\bar{h}^{\text{(old)}\ ab} = 0$. Why can this be the case?